# A very interesting question I am trying to solve in Thurstons 3 dimensional geometry and topology

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I found a pretty interesting problem in a wonderful book on three dimensional topology by Thurston. I have been thinking about the problem for awhile now, and am a little stumped. Here are the two questions to this problem:

1. Show that the linkage in the picture performs as advertised in its caption.
2. Construct a mechanical linkage that achieves straight line motion.

What do you guys think? I have plenty of rough sketches for the second one however, I am still a little unsure. As for the first, I was not sure how to go about this problem.

[image]

Comment: Hint for part 2 - what kind of figure inverts into a straight line? How can you constrain point $P$ to follow (part of) such a figure, so that $P'$ inverts into the invoice. For the first part if $O$ is the centre of the circle you need to prove $OP\cdot OP'$ is constant. Try drawing in the diagonals of the diamond and marking the centre $C$ and the unmarked corners of the diamond.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the text underneath the diagram gives you the radius of the circle in which the inversion happens. I've hidden the computations in case you want to have a go yourself. The mechanism for drawing a straight line is known as the Peaucellier Linkage.

Let $O$ be the anchor point marked by the triangle, $C$ be the centre of the diamond and $A$ and $B$ be the unmarked vertices of the diamond.

The condition for inversion is then $OP\cdot OP'=r^2=x^2-y^2$. We can verify this from the diagram:

> $$x^2=OA^2=OC^2+CA^2=(OP+PC)^2+CA^2=OP^2+2OP\cdot PC+(PC^2+CA^2)$$$$=OP\cdot(OP+2PC)+y^2=OP\cdot OP'+y^2$$

For part $2$

> A circle through $O$ inverts into a straight line - so we need to find a way of constraining $P$ to part of a circle through $O$. Then $P'$ will trace a straight line segment. Select point $D$ as a second anchor point, and join $P$ to $D$ using a straight rod of length $l=|OD|$ so that $P$ lies on the circle centre $D$ and radius $l$, which by construction passes through $O$.